# Skip Visual Studio Version Selector

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

I have created a C# project under Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Now I use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to edit my project. I have no problem for that, I can open, edit and save correctly my project.

The only thing that disturbing me is when I want to open my *.sln* project with VS Express, Visual Studio Version Selector is opened. In short, Windows doesn't recognize the project as a C# one but simply a a VS one.
Is there a way to open this particular (not all *.sln* files, I don't want Basic or C++ projects to be opened in VS C# Express...) project directly in VS C# Express?

P.S: Both my Visual Pro and Express versions are 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.

**EDIT :** That does not happen when I create a project with Visual Studio C# 2010 Express. In this case, the *.sln* file is recognized as a C# project.

Comment: That's great that you found your answer, and even better that you came back to include it! You should actually post it below as an answer, and then accept it, so that it's easier to find by others. There's no problem with accepting your own answers here, as long as they're the right answer! Also, welcome to Super User :)

Comment: @Darth Yes I know, I just don't have enough reputation yet to answer my owns questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found how to do it : edit the *.sln* file with a text editor and change the second line:

```
# Visual C# Express 2010
```

instead of:

```
# Visual Studio 2010
```

Comment: Finally you got that reputation ^^